# Prevent Android logcat clear during app restart

Tags: android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and it clears the logcat buffer during app restart. Now my app crashes, restarts and I don't see what happens just before the crash.

Is there a way for logcat in Android Studio not to clear during the app restart? I wanted to increase the logcat buffer size, but could not find the option it in the current version of AS.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I had the same issue, but looks more like a feature than a bug:

In AndroidStudio, the default setting for the Logcat window seems to be "Show only selected Application" (top right corner of the Logcat window)... which is looking at the log of the selected process (your current launch by default). So when your app crashes during testing, that process is gone, so the filter clears the log.

Instead, select "Edit Filter Configuration..." and set up a filter for your app, eg:

- FilterName: MyApp
- PackageName: com.example.myapp (<< replace with your app's package name)

...and then select that filter for future runs. This should keep the log there for you, even after the app crashes.

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040015/6058777)

Comment: Is there a way for preventing the app from restarting instead?

Comment: the great hack I think

Comment: While this is a solution, I've got the feeling that clearing the log was not a default setting before they changed something. I always thought that this was happening because I was using Crashlytics, that Crashlytics somehow intercepted the crash and somehow redirected the output to send it to Google, and while doing that, it cleared the log. The thing is, that if I let the app crash a second time, then the log won't get cleared, so I usually repeat the crashing condition to get access to the log (very annoying).

Answer (score 10):

In the device's developer settings, locate the option for "Always show crash dialog" and enable it:

[image: "Always show crash dialog" enabled in developer options]

By doing so, the application will not be restarted and the log for the process (before it died) will not be cleared in Android Studio.