# Wht when I use view binding for fragment, my app crass without any reason?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in android, and I try to use the view binding for my app, there is not any mistake on my code, but after running, it is crashed, when I look at the Logcat , there is not any info about crash
there is only one info about

> internal inner class MenuAdapter(context: MyFragment

as a

Parameter 'context' is never used, any idea?

```
   class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private  var _binding: MyFragment? = null
    private  val binding get() = _binding!!

    private var mTitle = arrayOf("menu1", "menu2", "menu3", "menu4", "menu5")

    private var images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.ic_menu1,
            R.drawable.ic_menu2,
            R.drawable.ic_menu3,
            R.drawable.ic_menu4,
            R.drawable.ic_menu5)

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = MyFragment.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val listView: ListView = binding.listViewMenu
        val adapter = MenuAdapter(this, mTitle, images)
        listView.adapter = adapter

        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            if (position == 0) {
                val intent = Intent(this.context, Menu1::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                val intent = Intent(this.context, Menu2::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                val intent = Intent(this.context, Menu3::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                val intent = Intent(this.context, Menu4::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                val intent = Intent(this.context, Menu5::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
          

        }

        return binding.root

    }

    internal inner class MenuAdapter(context: MyFragment,
                                   private var rTitle: Array<String>,
                                   private var rImgs: IntArray) : ArrayAdapter<String?>(requireContext(),
        R.layout.row_menu,
        R.id.textViewMenu, rTitle) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

            val menuRow = RowMenuBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            val images = menuRow.imageMenu
            val myTitle = menuRow.textViewMenu

            images.setImageResource(rImgs[position])
            myTitle.text = rTitle[position]
            return binding.root
        }}}
```

Comment: I think I have an idea. Try to handle UI elements like binding.listViewMenu in `onViewCreated`. For onCreateView just leave 2 lines: 1. binding assignment and return binding.root 
Also, another question: Shouldn't you use MyFragmentBinding instead of MyFragment ?

Comment: I bet there is a crash info in log, but app gets killed and log is cleaned then. try to configure log as in answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415101/prevent-android-logcat-clear-during-app-restart) and post stacktrace

Comment: @Ionut J. Bejan, I try to apply  onViewCreated, but still  is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter `getView()` you are returning `binding.root` which refers to the fragment layout binding. You should be returning `menuRow.root` instead.

And you should have an exception in the logcat. Just make sure you don't have any logcat filters or such that hide it.

Comment: omg yes I missed that point , tnx so much :))))

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreateView(...)` should only do

```
 override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = MyFragment.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
}
```

All the other stuff you're doing should be in:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    val listView: ListView = binding.listViewMenu
    val adapter = MenuAdapter(this, binding.title, images)
    listView.adapter = adapter
    ... etc

}
```

Comment: internal inner class MenuAdapter(context: MyFragment will be outside of onViewCreated or inside?

Comment: it is the same still

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few changes to your code.
The Fragment class can now receive a xml layout so you should pass it there.
The change would look like this:

`class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_main_fragment) // replace with the name of your layout`

Each XML layout gets a respective binding class that corresponds with the XML layout name. For example, if your layout is called `my_main_fragment`, the class will receive the name of `MyMainFragmentBinding`.
Following that change, you will bind your view inside the `onViewCreated()` method. It will look like:

```
    private var _binding: MyMainFragmentBinding? = null
    private  val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _binding = MyMainFragmentBinding.bind(view)
    
    // ...other code from onCreateView
    }

    internal inner class MenuAdapter(context: MyFragment, ...
```

Also, don't forget to add `_binding = null` in the onDestroyView() method

To answer the question from the comments:
Inside getView() of your MenuAdapter, you should be returning `menuRow.root`.

You can read more about view binding at the android developers page: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Or see an example here: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/ViewBindingSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/viewbindingsample/BindFragment.kt#L36-L41

Comment: I do it but it is throw an error for an error here myTitle.text = rTitle[position]
            return binding.root for binding as Unresolved reference: binding

Comment: @Barışzüngür I believe you should `return menuRow.root` in your getView on the MenuAdapter.

Comment: tnx so much I get it :)