# No stacktrace in Android Studio with one plus 5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, oneplusone

With the One Plus 5 I don't get any stacktraces in logcat. Same mac same project with the nexus 6 I get them. This is happening on multiple projects so I guess this is a device issue but there seems nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Well it's a new phone, I suppose anything is possible.  Are there workarounds you can use in place of logcat?

Comment: I just tried with my OnePlus 5 and I have logcat as expected. Using latest Canary version of AS.

Comment: Are you sure you havent applied a filter. Make sure you have selected the correct device in the android monitor (top left), as well as the correct app.

Comment: I have oneplus 5 device and just check, I am able to get stacktrace as expected in logcat.

Comment: I checked the obvious steps, eg I am working on an app and it crashed. With the one plus 5 plugged in no stacktrace. Same crash just with the nexus 6 I get one in logcat. Yes I have double checked filters. My AS version is 2.4

Comment: Have you installed ADB drivers for the device ? Is your device visible in Android Monitor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been answered [on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040015/1972883)  this is due to the fact that you are viewing the LogCat for the selected process. 
So naturally when the process dies you get no logs.

You can instead create a filter based on your package name and you can keep getting logs after your application crashes.