# android app crashes when adding firebase ML vision dependencies with firebase database dependencies

Tags: android, google-vision, firebase-mlkit

I have a project which uses firebase database,auth and other dependencies but whenever i try to add firebase ml vision or google play service vision dependencie the app crashes although gradle build was successful.

[image: This is the image of my gradle]

edit : thats what logcat look like

```
06-27 02:36:37.757 17719-17719/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start I/zygote:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:281)
        at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() (SourceFile:37)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (SourceFile:31)
06-27 02:36:37.758 17719-17719/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start I/zygote:     at android.app.ContentProviderHolder android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(android.content.Context, android.app.ContentProviderHolder, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean, boolean, boolean) (ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(android.content.Context, java.util.List) (ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class** "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfjm" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/d
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim.zzdx(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable, boolean) (SourceFile:739)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze() (SourceFile:709)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String) (SourceFile:328)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) (SourceFile:294)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:281)
        at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() (SourceFile:37)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1917)
06-27 02:36:37.759 17719-17719/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start I/zygote:     at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (SourceFile:31)
        at android.app.ContentProviderHolder android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(android.content.Context, android.app.ContentProviderHolder, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean, boolean, boolean) (ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(android.content.Context, java.util.List) (ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
06-27 02:36:37.760 17719-17719/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcmb>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzfjm;
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim.zzdx(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable, boolean) (SourceFile:739)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze() (SourceFile:709)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String) (SourceFile:328)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) (SourceFile:294)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:281)
        at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() (SourceFile:37)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (SourceFile:31)
        at android.app.ContentProviderHolder android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(android.content.Context, android.app.ContentProviderHolder, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean, boolean, boolean) (ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(android.content.Context, java.util.List) (ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfjm" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start-qaVCC6CsVTDhpZWzHSJoXg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/d
06-27 02:36:37.761 17719-17719/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim.zzdx(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable, boolean) (SourceFile:739)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze() (SourceFile:709)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String) (SourceFile:328)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) (SourceFile:294)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:281)
        at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() (SourceFile:37)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (SourceFile:31)
        at android.app.ContentProviderHolder android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(android.content.Context, android.app.ContentProviderHolder, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean, boolean, boolean) (ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(android.content.Context, java.util.List) (ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
06-27 02:36:37.763 17719-17719/com.example.nikhiljindal.testing_start I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcmc>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzfjm;
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcim.zzdx(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable, boolean) (SourceFile:739)
        at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze() (SourceFile:709)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String) (SourceFile:328)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) (SourceFile:294)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:281)
        at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() (SourceFile:37)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (SourceFile:31)

    read: unexpected EOF!
```

Comment: What does the error/stacktrace of the crash look like?

Comment: if you meant logcat it remains empty as the app crashes before it start . and also please take a look  at the build.gradle file image i uploaded and i think the problem is due to version mismatch between dependencies .

Comment: Please don't post code or error message as images but include them in your answer. Did you try resolving the version mismatch? Did you try the approach described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568985/android-studio-logcat-cleans-after-app-closes to get logging?

Comment: thats for the help with logcat . now please also take a look at it

Comment: Please properly format you stacktrace and then try to search for the error(s) here on stackoverflow. This looks like a common problem (given what I could spot with the current formatting)

Comment: i already tried searching . i have highlighted some text in the logcat see if you can make something from it

Comment: @NikhilJindal you should use the latest version of firebase libraries check my answer hope it helps you and also its better to add code in text not in picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have firebase in your project, you should use the latest version based [on this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) like:

```
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

Pick what you want, also make sure that in your app gradle google services is updated too: ([check this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup))

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You firebase dependencies must be with same versions, after clean and build the project